Image Warped in jsPDF PDF Generation, Cannot Set Auto Height and Image Not Appearing in PDF Due to Mixed Content Issues
I'm working on generating a PDF in a web application using jsPDF. One of the challenges I'm facing is adding a logo image to the header of the PDF while maintaining the correct aspect ratio and ensuring it doesn't get warped. I also encountered a mixed content issue, where the image is served over HTTP while the page is loaded over HTTPS.
Problem: Image Warping in PDF
I need to dynamically set the image height based on its original aspect ratio. According to jsPDF documentation, I cannot set imgHeight to auto, so I tried calculating the image height using the following formula to maintain the aspect ratio:
var imgHeight = (img.height / img.width) * imgWidth;
Current Code for Adding Image:
   function downloadPDF(submissionId, formJSON) {
            console.log('Downloading PDF for submission ID formJSON:', formJSON);
            var submissionCard = document.getElementById('submission-card');
            var pdf = new window.jspdf.jsPDF();
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var doc = parser.parseFromString(submissionCard.innerHTML, 'text/html');

    // Function to load the image and convert it to base64
    function getBase64Image(img) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        return canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); // Returns base64 of the image
    }

    // Add logos as header to each page
    function addHeader(pdf, logoSrc, format) {
        if (logoSrc && format) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = logoSrc;

            img.onload = function () {
                var pageWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
                var imgWidth = logoSize; // Width of the image
                var imgHeight = (img.height / img.width) * imgWidth; // Maintain aspect ratio

                var x = (pageWidth - imgWidth) / 2; // Center the image horizontally

                // Convert the image to base64 and add to PDF
                var base64Image = getBase64Image(img);
                pdf.addImage(base64Image, format, x, 10, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            };

            img.onerror = function () {
                console.error('Error loading image:', logoSrc);
            };
        }
    }
    
   
           // Load all logos, process nodes, and then add headers
            Promise.all(logos.map(loadImage)).then(async (loadedLogos) => {
                // Process all content nodes
                for (const node of doc.body.childNodes) {
                    // await processNode(node, loadedLogos, getImageFormat(loadedLogos[0].src));
                    await processNode(node, loadedLogos, loadedLogos.length > 0 ? getImageFormat(loadedLogos[0].src) : null);
                }

                // Add headers to each page
                var totalPages = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
                for (var i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
                    pdf.setPage(i);
                    var logo = loadedLogos[i % loadedLogos.length];
                    var format = getImageFormat(logos[i % logos.length]);
                    addHeader(pdf, logo, format);
                }

                // Save the generated PDF
                pdf.save('submission-' + submissionId + '.pdf');
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error('Error loading images:', error);
            });
        }

Problem: When I use this logic, image is not being displayed because of a mixed content error. The page is being loaded over HTTPS, but the images are being served over HTTP.
I tried to resolve this issue by using ngrok to set up a secure connection (HTTPS) for the application. However, the problem persists. I fetch the image and convert it to Base64 for adding to the PDF. This issue prevents the logo from being displayed in the PDF.
How can I properly set the image height in jsPDF to maintain the aspect ratio without warping the image?
